# move a bucket to other storage class

Tags: google-cloud-storage, bucket

I want to transfer a complete bucket to coldline easy. My problem is that when I try to run `gsutil`, it disconnects and charges me each time.

This is the command I'm trying to use:

```
gsutil rewrite -s coldline gs: // bucket / **
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, David. Does the command give any error message when you execute it? Is there anything happening on the google side maybe?

Answer (score 3):

You can use a [lifecycle policy](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/lifecycle#actions) on the bucket to downgrade all objects in the bucket to coldline.